# Python SMBus write_byte and values greater than 1 byte (255)

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

Using i2C to communicate between a RaspberryPi and Arduino. In my Python code I have the following, where foo represents an integer from 0-255.
The problem is when the value is greater than 255, which, according to my understanding, greater than a single byte. 
Can anyone tell me how I might alter the following so that values greater than 255 are properly sent over a serial connection?

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
bus.write_byte(0x04, foo)
```

Comment: You have to serialize the value into two or more bytes, which involves the receiving side knowing how many bytes and in what order to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on the device you are writing to, but:

```
my_data = (0x10, 0x11, 0x20, 0x32)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(dev_address, dev_reg, my_data)
```

This sends a block of data to device with address `dev_address` to register `dev_reg`, and the data octets (bytes) ar in `my_data`.

There is nothing magical in `dev_reg`, it is just usually the command/register octet in SMBus, i.e. it is the first byte sent after the address.

---

If you just want to send 16 bits (integer `i`) to a device with address `dev_address`, you could use:

```
bus.write_i2c_block_data(dev_address, i & 0xff, ((i >> 8) & 0xff,))
```

This command actually combines the second argument (device register) and the payload (list of octets) and sends them combined. Very often the first data octet is a command or register number. Here the first octet of the 16-bit word (the least significant octet) is sent in place of the device register, and the second octet (most significant octet) is send in the payload.

However, for this specific case you could also use the `write_byte_data` call:

```
bus.write_byte_data(dev_address, i & 0xff, (i >> 8) & 0xff)
```

Both of these function calls are intended for a protocol where each device has an 8-bit register number in addition to the device address. The I2C only specifies that there is a 7-bit address for each device, and the rest is up to the application.

So, wither of the instructions above should just send:

```
<start>
<7-bit address> + <write bit>
<8-bit byte>
<8-bit byte>
<stop>
```

Very often the first 8-bit octet is a device register.

If you want to read something from a device, the simple case is:

```
<start>
<device address> + <read bit>
<read octet #1>
...
<stop>
```

However, very often you want to communicate the register number to the device, in which case you need to send:

```
<start>
<device address> + <write bit>
<8 bits: register number>
<start>
<device address> + <read bit>
<read octet #1>
...
<stop>
```

Because these interactions are a bit complicated, they are wrapped in the API commands.